# Community User deleted a question I answered

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, community-user

The Community user deleted a question I had an accepted answer on.
If it was a low quality post, I would have expected a close reason and then the delete votes. That didn't happen here, though.

Why was this question deleted?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333635/remove-html-tag-from-string-regex/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was deleted because the author's account was deleted, and all of their negatively scored questions are deleted when a user is deleted.

Comment: Oh, any reason it didn't notify me of this, I usually get a `User removed` notice when this happens. (or maybe that is only when the user upvoted an answer of mine and they are deleted?)

Comment: @chris85 The user removed notice is there when a *vote* on one of your posts is removed due to a user being deleted (and their votes going with them).  That's not the case here.  Your rep changed due to a deleted post, which is what the rep page is telling you.  It just so happens that the post was removed due to a user being removed in this case.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clarification.